# When is every spanning tree of a connected graph the union of spanning trees of its subgraphs?

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a finite connected simple graph. By the union $H\cup K$ of two graph $H$ and $K$ we shall mean the graph with edge-set $E(H)\cup E(K)$ and vertex-set $V(H)\cup V(K)$.

For which collections of *edge-disjoint* subgraphs $H_1,H_2,\ldots,H_r$ with $H_1\cup H_2\cup\cdots\cup H_r=G$ is it true that every spanning tree $T$ of $G$ is a union $T=T_1\cup T_2\cup\cdots\cup T_r$ with $T_i$ a spanning tree for $H_i$?

I suspect this holds at least when $H_1,H_2,\ldots,H_r$ are the blocks (that is, the maximal biconnected subgraphs) of $G$...

Does it alter the conclusion if we omit the assumption that $G$ is simple?

Very thankful for any help.

Comment: Have found some sufficient conditions for this to be true, but no necessary conditions so far. Sufficient, at least, is for each $H_i$ to be a union of blocks of $G$, in such a way that $H_1,H_2,\ldots H_r$ constitute a "partition" of the blocks of $G$. In particular, it holds whenever $H_1,H_2,\ldots H_r$ are the blocks of $G$. Can provide a proof of this if anyone is interested. Have not managed to show that this is a necessary condition (nor to find a counterexample showing that it isn't).

Comment: In general, if the proposition holds for some $\{H_i\}$, then it holds for any "coarser partition" of $\{H_i\}$ as well.

Answer (score 0):

We want to guarantee that $T$ has no cycles. Indeed, if $H_1, \dots, H_r$ are the blocks of $G$, then no cycle can be created by taking unions of $T_i$, since blocks have by definition a tree structure. By similar reasoning, this is also true for any coarser partition.

Now, observe that bridges are uninteresting, since they must be contained in any spanning tree. Observe also that any subgraph with exactly one vertex can be added to the union of subgraphs. We may also assume that each $H_i$ is connected, as it otherwise does not have a spanning tree.

Suppose that there exists a block $B$ of $G$ that is divided into two edge disjoint subgraphs $H_1$ and $H_2$, i.e., $H_1\cup H_2 = B$. If one of $H_1$ or $H_2$ only contain a single vertex, then the other is the entirety of $B$. Suppose this does not occur. Since $B$ is a block, $H_1$ and $H_2$ intersect in at least two vertices. Thus,

$$|V(H_1)|+|V(H_2)| \geq |V(B)|+2,$$

so, as a tree on $n$ vertices has $n-1$ edges,
$$
|E(T_1)|+|E(T_2)|\geq |V(B)|>|V(B)|-1,
$$
but any spanning tree of $B$ has $|V(B)|-1$ edges. We conclude that $T_1\cup T_2$ contains a cycle. Thus, $T_1\cup T_2$ is not contained in any spanning tree of $G$. In fact, the same argument holds whenever we split a block into more than one subgraph. What we have shown is the following:

> Let $B$ be a block of $G$. If $H_1, \dots, H_r$ is a desired collection of subgraphs, then for all $1\leq i\leq r$, $E(H_i)\cap E(B) \in \{\emptyset, E(B)\}$.

Together with our previous observations, we have in other words: $H_1, \dots, H_r$ is a desired collection of subgraphs if and only if it is the block decomposition of $G$ together with some singleton subgraphs, or a coarsification of the block decomposition of $G$ together with some singleton subgraphs.